# Tree traversal with corecursion

Tags: algorithm, clojure

I'm trying to figure out corecursion in Clojure with nontrivial (i.e. not Fibonacci), but manageable, examples. Apparently it is possible to implement binary tree traversal with corecursion. Wikipedia has an example in Python which I am unable to understand.

How can I implement it in Clojure? Let's say I'm looking for BFS, but it could be any order.

Here's what I have so far:

```
(defstruct tree :val :left :right)

(def my-tree (struct tree 1 (struct tree 2) (struct tree 3 4 5)))

(def bfs (lazy-cat [my-tree] (map #(:left %) bfs) (map #(:right %) bfs) ))

(println (take 4 bfs))
```

Unfortunately it seems to be going all the way to the left, ignoring the right branch.

Comment: Can you link to the python code, or give more detail about what exactly you're trying to get the code to do?  Pasting broken code doesn't provide enough insight.  ;)

On a potentially related note, `letfn` provides a way to do mutual recursion.

Comment: @ataggart: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion

Comment: Insufficient data for meaningful answer.

Comment: @ataggart: Really? I thought it was a valid "how do I do in Clojure what you can read here in Python & Haskell" question. (And pretty challenging too.)

Comment: It might be, but only to those who already understand the text of the article and what the Haskell code is trying to do; I'm willing to accept it as a personal flaw that I can do neither.  This was why I asked the OP to state what he wants his code to do, rather than trying to parse a wikipedia article clearly written not to explain a concept, but to show off how smart the authors are.

Comment: @ataggart: I'm definitely not going to defend the Wikipedia article, it feels more like a sketch or a list of concepts to be described in a proper article... Note that the question does state that the OP is looking for a breadth-first tree traversal solution in Clojure though. Anyway, nice answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming Michal's code does what you want, this also works:

```
(defn bftrav [& trees]
  (when trees
    (concat trees 
      (->> trees
        (mapcat #(vector (:left %) (:right%)))
        (filter identity)
        (apply bftrav)))))
```

Comment: This is so nice... +1. You could replace `#(vector ...)` with `(juxt :left :right)` to make it even prettier. :-)

Comment: And I was just saying to myself the other day, "what's the point of juxt?"  Excellent!

Comment: Doesn't it run bftrav over and over for the same nodes in each iteration?

Comment: Or: What purpose does (filter identity) serve?

Comment: Nope.  It returns a lazy sequence of a tree's sub-trees by recursing on the set of sub-trees in each tier, which is how the breadth-first behavior is achieved.  For a balanced tree of seven nodes, bftrav would be called 3 times, one for each level.

Now, whether that's what you wanted is a whole separate matter.

Comment: (filter identity) just filters out the nil values that would be in the sequence when a node didn't have a :left or :right child; I prefer it to (filter #(not (nil? %))) or (filter (complement nil?)).  An alternative would be make the function used by mapcat smarter, but I was going for simplicity.

Comment: It occurs to me that the above should either replace `concat` with `lazy-cat` or wrap the body with `lazy-seq`; otherwise `when` causes the "rest" part of the generated sequence to be forced at each step and the generation is not lazy. With the change, the code remains beautiful *and* becomes fully lazy.

Comment: Quite right, though the extra laziness is undone by the call to apply, which will force traversal of the seq returned from each recursion.  This is also the problem with the mapcat implementation.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348719#3357201

Comment: Disregard my comment about apply, I was confused.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a direct translation of the `bftrav` Haskell function from the Wikipedia article. Note that it uses a `letrec` macro I've just written -- see [this Gist](http://gist.github.com/486880) for the latest version.

I've changed your definition of `my-tree` to read thus:

```
(def my-tree (struct tree 1 (struct tree 2) (struct tree 3 (struct tree 4) (struct tree 5))))
```

Also, my `leaf?` function assumes that we're only dealing with proper two-way branches and leaf nodes (so a `nil` on the `:left` branch implies a `nil` on the `:right` branch); it shouldn't be two difficult to change this to handle single-child "branches":

```
(defn leaf? [t] (nil? (:left t)))
```

The code for `bftrav` is as follows:

```
(defn bftrav [t]
  (letrec [queue (lazy-seq (cons t (trav 1 queue)))
           trav (fn [l q]
                  (lazy-seq
                    (cond (zero? l) nil
                          (leaf? (first q)) (trav (dec l) (rest q))
                          :else (let [{:keys [left right]} (first q)]
                                  (cons left (cons right (trav (inc l) (rest q))))))))]
    queue))
```

An example from the REPL:

```
user> (bftrav my-tree)
({:val 1, :left {:val 2, :left nil, :right nil}, :right {:val 3, :left {:val 4, :left nil, :right nil}, :right {:val 5, :left nil, :right nil}}} {:val 2, :left nil, :right nil} {:val 3, :left {:val 4, :left nil, :right nil}, :right {:val 5, :left nil, :right nil}} {:val 4, :left nil, :right nil} {:val 5, :left nil, :right nil})
user> (count (bftrav my-tree))
5
```