# Partitioning in clojure with a lazy collection of strings

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

Starting with a collection of strings like:

```
(def str-coll ["abcd" "efgh" "jklm"])
```

The goal is to extract off a specific number of characters from the head of the string collection, generating a partitioned grouping of strings. This is the desired behavior:

```
(use '[clojure.contrib.str-utils2 :only (join)])
(partition-all 3 (join "" str-coll))

((\a \b \c) (\d \e \f) (\g \h \j) (\k \l \m))
```

However, using join forces evaluation of the entire collection, which causes memory issues when dealing with very large collections of strings. My specific use case is generating subsets of strings from a lazy collection generated by parsing a large file of delimited records:

```
(defn file-coll [in-file]
  (->> (line-seq (reader in-file))
    (partition-by #(.startsWith ^String % ">"))
    (partition 2))))
```

and is building on work from [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303848/improving-clojure-lazy-seq-usage-for-iterative-text-parsing). I've tried combinations of reduce, partition and join but can't come up with the right incantation to pull characters from the head of the first string and lazily evaluate subsequent strings as needed. Thanks much for any ideas or pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're going for, but the following does what your first example does, and does so lazily.

Step-by-step for clarity:

```
user=> (def str-coll ["abcd" "efgh" "jklm"])
#'user/str-coll
user=> (map seq str-coll)
((\a \b \c \d) (\e \f \g \h) (\j \k \l \m))
user=> (flatten *1)
(\a \b \c \d \e \f \g \h \j \k \l \m)
user=> (partition 3 *1)
((\a \b \c) (\d \e \f) (\g \h \j) (\k \l \m))
```

All together now:

```
(->> str-coll 
  (map seq)
  flatten
  (partition 3))
```

Comment: No need to flatten, just concat the character sequences by using mapcat:

(partition-all 3 (mapcat seq str-coll))

Comment: ataggart and Jürgen, thanks much for the solutions: mapping to a seq was exactly what I was missing. Getting over that hurdle led me to realize that partition-by wasn't acting as lazily as I'd hoped. While each partition is provided in a lazy manner, the individual components of each partition are not; so partitioning the initial file at delimiters does not provide the desired lazy strings that feed into this.

Comment: @Jürgen: mapcat isn't lazy (it uses apply), hence why I didn't use it.

Comment: @ataggart: Nope, It is! Just check: (type (mapcat seq str-coll))

Why should apply prevent laziness?

Comment: @Jürgen: mapcat returns a lazy seq, but how that comes into existence isn't fully lazy.  See my additional "answer" for more info.

Comment: @ataggart. This isn't about apply. It's about the function which is applied. concat will never realize the "&rest of it's argument list until used in construction of the lazy sequence.
Just check the implementation.

Comment: @Jürgen: concat is irrelevant since the problem is the non-laziness of apply immediately prior to invoking concat.  I urge you to read the more detailed answer I provided, and/or look at the implementation of apply.

Comment: @Jürgen:Since concat works on strings, seq is unnecessary: `(partition-all 3 (apply concat str-coll))` and `(partition-all 3 (mapcat identity str-coll))` both work too :)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: EVERYTHING I'VE WRITTEN WAS WRONG**

When a function with a var-arg is applied to with a seq longer than the number of discrete args, the remainder of the seq is passed as the var-arg (see [RestFn.applyTo](http://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RestFn.java#L130)).

To Jürgen: I'm stupid. You're smart. I was wrong. You were right. You're the best. I'm the worst. You're very good-looking. I'm not attractive.

The following is a record of my idiocy...

---

Responding to Jürgen Hötzel's comment.

`mapcat` isn't fully lazy because `apply` isn't lazy in evaluating the number of args to apply. Further, `apply` can't be lazy because functions must be invoked with a discrete number of args.  Currently if the number of args exceeds 20, the remaining args are dumped into an array, hence non-lazy.

So looking at the source for `mapcat`:

```
(defn mapcat
  "Returns the result of applying concat to the result of applying map
  to f and colls.  Thus function f should return a collection."
  {:added "1.0"}
  [f & colls]
    (apply concat (apply map f colls)))
```

If we expand the evaluation out using the example, the inner `apply` would evaluate to:

```
user=> (map seq str-coll)
((\a \b \c \d) (\e \f \g \h) (\j \k \l \m))
```

which is fine since the `str-coll` doesn't get fully realized, but then the outer `apply` would evaluate to:

```
user=> (concat '(\a \b \c \d) '(\e \f \g \h) '(\j \k \l \m))
(\a \b \c \d \e \f \g \h \j \k \l \m)
```

Note that the outer `apply` applies *n* arguments to `concat`, one for each string in the original `str-coll`.  Now, it's true that the result of `concat` is lazy, and each arg is itself lazy, but you still need realize the full length of `str-coll` to get those *n* lazy seqs. If `str-coll` has 1000 strings, then `concat` will get 1000 args, and all 1000 strings would need to be read out of the file and into memory before `concat` could be called.

---

For the unbelivers, a demonstration of the seq-realizing behavior of apply:

```
user=> (defn loud-seq [] (lazy-seq (println "HELLO") (cons 1 (loud-seq))))
#'user/loud-seq
user=> (take 3 (loud-seq)) ; displaying the lazy-seq realizes it, thus printing HELLO
(HELLO
HELLO
1 HELLO
1 1)
user=> (do (take 3 (loud-seq)) nil) ; lazy-seq not realized; no printing of HELLO
nil
user=> (do (apply concat (take 3 (loud-seq))) nil) ; draw your own conclusions
HELLO
HELLO
HELLO
nil
```

And a demonstration that varargs are not lazy:

```
user=> (defn foo [& more] (type more))
#'user/foo
user=> (foo 1 2 3 4)
clojure.lang.ArraySeq
user=> (apply foo (repeat 4 1))
clojure.lang.Cons
```

Though as counterpoint, that the following works baffles me:

```
user=> (take 10 (apply concat (repeat [1 2 3 4])))
(1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2)
```

Comment: There is no "get all those n lazy seqs". concat is invoked with a "lazy argument list". You can check this in our example practical by setting the string collection to a infinite lazy list:

(def str-coll (repeat "abcd"))

And then just take part of the result:

(take 10 (partition-all 3 (mapcat seq str-coll)))

Comment: Please see the edit at the bottom of my post for more proof of my claim.

Comment: Also, concat is not invoked with a "lazy argument list".  There's no such thing.  All function invocation occurs by passing a discrete number of args to a function.  You can see this in the invoke methods of IFn here: http://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IFn.java That the function declares, e.g., [& coll], simply means that the args to are wrapped in a (non-lazy) seq.

Comment: Though your point regarding apply working with an infinite series has me baffled.